# is angular ViewEncapsulation necessary?

Tags: angular, angular-material2, angular2viewencapsulation

I was a big fan of ViewEncapsulation in angular components. But I see if we set it to ViewEncapsulation.None - we can also encapsulate styles by just component selector in SCSS. For example:

```
my-component {
  h1 {}
  button {}
 etc..
}
```

Also If I want to use for example some material.angular component and customize it inside my-component it's easier and clean without Encapsulation:

When Encapsulation is on:

```
:host ::ng-deep (which is deprecated) {
  mat-expansion-panel {
    some-internals {}
  }
}
```

When Encapsulation is off:

```
my-component {
  mat-expansion-panel {
    some-internals {}
  }
}
```

What do you think about that? are there some arguments to use Encapsulation and not go by selector encapsulation pattern?